# 'None stream removed' error while sending multiple continous 'synthesize_speech' requests using same client in google TTS (python)

Tags: grpc, google-text-to-speech, gtts

As you can see in the code below, I have initialized a TTS client and using that client to synthesize outputs for all requests. This is giving errors. But, if I initialize client for each request by putting code - `client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()` inside the generator function, it works fine.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from google.cloud import texttospeech


app = Flask(__name__)

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = '/path/to/json'

# Initialize client
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code="en-US", ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL
)
audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16
)

@app.route('/generate', methods=['GET'])
def generator():
    text = request.args.get('text')

    # Google TTS
    synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text=text)
    response = client.synthesize_speech(input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config)

    return 'some variable'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host = '0.0.0.0', port='8000', threaded=False)
```

Now, when I am sending multiple requests like this -

```
for i in range(100):
    requests.get('ip:port/generate', {'text': 'some large text. ' * 200})
```

Initial 3-4 requests work good. After that, some requests start getting Internal Error (500). This is the full traceback -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 73, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 923, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
        details = "Stream removed"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1614073936.608639390","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:74.125.142.95:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1067,"grpc_message":"Stream removed","grpc_status":2}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/current/app/path/deploy.py", line 37, in video_generator
    response = client.synthesize_speech(input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config)
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/texttospeech_v1/services/text_to_speech/client.py", line 374, in synthesize_speech
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/some/path/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 75, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
    # Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
google.api_core.exceptions.Unknown: None Stream removed
```